# Showing $p$ divides $(p-2)!-1$ when $p$ is prime

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

How might one show that $p$ divides $(p-2)!-1$ where $p$ is a prime number? I am not even sure if it is true but I have been randomly trying it on some primes and it seems to be true.

Comment: Does not compute. Only 1 and p dividies p for p prime.

Comment: Do you know Wilson's Theorem? $(p-1)!\equiv -1\pmod{p}$. Hence $(p-2)!(p-1) \equiv (p-1)\pmod{p}$, and cancelling $p-1$ (which is relatively prime to $p$) we get $(p-2)!\equiv 1\pmod{p}$.

Comment: Did you mean "$p$ divides $(p-2)!-1$"?

Comment: @all: [Laylady's comment] answers an earlier version of the question (which asked why $(p-2)!-1$ divides $p$).

Comment: @MichaelHardy: of course you are right, careless me. :)

Comment: @ArturoMagidin: Interesting theorem, thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Indeed it is, this is a simple corollary of Wilson's theorem: If $p$ is prime, then $(p-1)! \equiv -1$ mod p (the converse is also true, but we don't need that).

So, assuming Wilson's theorem, $-1 \equiv (p-1)! \equiv (p-1)(p-2)!\equiv -(p-2)!$ from which we immediately get $(p-2)! \equiv 1$ mod p.

To prove Wilson's theorem, see here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilson%27s_theorem

Edit: Whoops, I see I was beaten to this answer in the comment thread, sorry.

Comment: Thank you, I don't know why the accept this answer button would't work...