# solution verification of least residue

Tags: elementary-number-theory, solution-verification

I want to find the least residue of $95!$ mod $97$. So I wanna solve
$$95! \equiv_{97} x$$
where $x \in \mathbb{Z}^+$ is minimum, but Wilsons theorem

$$96! \equiv_{97} -1$$

so multiplying the top equation by 96 I obtain

$$-1 \equiv_{97} 96x$$

which forces $x=1$. Did I do this correctly using Wilsons theorem?

Comment: Just to be sure, the $19$'s are meant to be $97,$ right? If so then I agree, but if not then it's clearly false because $19 \leq 95 \Rightarrow 19 | 95! \Rightarrow 95! \equiv_{19} 0$

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Showing $p$ divides $(p-2)!-1$ when $p$ is prime](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/102378/showing-p-divides-p-2-1-when-p-is-prime) (note that $97$ is prime) - found using an [Approach0 search](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24(p-2)!%5Cequiv%201%5Cpmod%7Bp%7D%24&p=1).

Comment: @StephenDonovan yes edit made. Does it work ?